# Nginx location - sites configuration not working

Tags: nginx, location, sites

i have an nginx running with a location :

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://10.22.1.27:3000;
               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Connection "";
}
```

as a result my application comes up

when I change the location to

```
location /login {
     proxy_pass http://10.22.1.27:3000;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Connection "";
    
}
```

My application is not coming up at all. In the console I get the following error message :

ET https://demo3.xxxxx.rocks/static/js/vendor.f9538d6f661cb0e94054.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Any idea what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) tells NGINX how to handle requests when the path matches the given pattern.

`location /` will match any path, or more precisely, anything starting with `/`, which is effectively any request.  So that already includes `/login` and any other page or path you navigate to.

When you changed it to `location /login`, it would no longer match `/` when you first navigated to the address, which would cause `HTTP 404 Not Found`.

I know you haven't used this but just to make the point, note that `location /` is different from `location = /`, because the second case would only match if the path is *exactly* `/`, so it would no longer match `/login`.

Bottom line: leave it as `location /` unless you have specific needs to handle different paths in different ways.  For example, you might handle requests at `/api/...` with a `proxy_pass` to a backend, but `/docs/...` requests by serving static files from a local directory.

EDIT: Also, if you do change the location path, bear in mind it will append that to the `proxy_pass` address.  So a request to `/login/foo` will be forwarded to `http://10.22.1.27:3000/login/foo`.  If the upstream server doesn't recognise the `/login` path then that will fail with `404 Not Found`.

To fix that, add a path to your `proxy_pass`, even if it is just a root path, for example `http://10.22.1.27:3000/` (note the trailing slash).  Then NGINX will map the `location` path to the `proxy_pass` path, and only append what's left.  For example, now a request to `/login/foo` will be forwarded to `http://10.22.1.27:3000/foo`.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I have different backends. This is why we want to use the location. they all run against different internal instances ( different IP and Port ) . But still I don't understand while the same application works via location / and not via /login as the definition within the location block is not changing . Why can't the files no not be found anymore or what do I need to do ?

Comment: When you try changing the location from `/` to `/login`, are you also changing the client-side to call for example `/login/foo` instead of  `/foo`?  If not, then that's why it is failing, you can't change the path at one end without changing it the same way at the other.  If you *are* changing both ends and that's why it should be working, that's probably because of the `proxy_pass` - see edited answer.

Comment: Yes, u are right. I change the path in my application as well and it is working . Thank you so much